# Javascript variables not being instantiated

Tags: javascript

I don't know why, but the alert appears if placed above the variable, but not below.

```
<script>
            var clicked = False;
            alert("Variables instantiated");
</script>
```

**EDIT**: From the future, yes; this is a terribly noob question that could be, and has been solved by learning Javascript and reading the docs.

Comment: `var clicked = false;`

Comment: `False` is not defined, so you're probably getting a JavaScript error, preventing the `alert` line. `false` is the correct keyword.

Comment: Press F12 and check the console for errors to help you debug this

Comment: javascript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should do in situations like this is check your browser console. In this case you would have found an error saying something like, `False is not defined`. This is because JavaScript is case sensitive, and the boolean false value is written `false`. Because you're writing it as `False`, JavaScript is looking for a variable by that name, which doesn't exist.

Besides the advice to look for errors, the solution to your problem is to write your code as:

```
var clicked = false;
```